# Acessando variável em outra classe vem nulo - C# Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, datagridview

Ola, eu sei que é uma pergunta besta, mas estou tendo dificuldades, para acessar uma variável de outra classe.
Situação:
- Estou usando um datagrid, a qual quero pegar o valor de uma coluna, e transportar esse valor para outra classe.

**Script:**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string idString;
    public int idselecionada;

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {           
        idString = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        idselecionada = Int32.Parse(idString);
        MessageBox.Show("ID " + idselecionada);
    }
```

Esse script funciona perfeitamente. Eu clico na linha ele pega o valor da primeira coluna, e me mostra esse valor.
Mas quando tento acessar o valor de outra classe não consigo.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int idinicial;
    Form2 varivavel2 = new Form2();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        idinicial = varivavel2.idselecionada;
        MessageBox.Show("ID Inicial " + idinicial);
    }
```

O Problema é que quando abro o Form 1, ele aparece o Messagebox com um valor em zero. Já tentei isso de várias formas, mas não consegui fazer funcionar.

**Situação:**

Eu estou tentando montar uma programação de cadastro de clientes simples, com nome telefone endereço essas coisas.
Na Form2 é a tela aonde tem um Datagrid, com as informações, do banco de dados.
Eu estou tentando criar um botão, para alterar os dados do cliente, eu clico no registro que quero, ao clicar é pego o ID do registro, clico no botão alterar e abre o Form1 ja no registro que foi selecionado no Form2.

Desde ja obrigado.

Comment: Por que transforma algo em `string` e depois em `int`?

Comment: Eu sou meio noob, meio que peguei o script pela net. Se eu tirar o ToString, ele ovalor sera integral? ou sera como objeto?

Answer (score 1):

tenta encapsular fica menos suscetivo a erros

```
    form2:

private string idString;

{

get{ return idString; }

set{ idString = value; }

}
public int idselecionada;

{

get{ return idselecionada; }

set{ idselecionada = value; }

}
```

ai no form 1 vc usaria assim :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int idinicial;
    Form2 varivavel2 = new Form2();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          

        MessageBox.Show("ID Inicial " + variavel2.idinicial);
    }
```

Comment: vou tentar e ja te informo se funcionou.

Comment: Tentei dessa forma mas não funcionou. Continua apresentando nullo da mesma forma.

Answer (score 1):

Bom tente cirar uma classe controladora de instancia, você provavelmente está chamando o click  em uma instancia diferente do  do local do click

```
public static class ControleInstancia 
{
    public static Form2 Fomulario2;
}
```

refira todo a instancia da classe Form2 nessa vairavel faça o seguinte para veirificar se ela já está na memoria.
Você provavelmente  inicia a  view  de em algum local de seu codigo

```
if(ControleInstancia.Fomulario2 == null){
    ControleInstancia.Fomulario2 = new  Form2();
}
```

Agora em  seu form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int idinicial;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          

        MessageBox.Show("ID Inicial " + ControleInstancia.Fomulario2.idinicial);
    }
}
```

Lembre-se de fazer o start do  seu  form2;
E sempre chamar pela class de controle de instancia.

Answer (score 1):

No Form1, na linha `Form2 varivavel2 = new Form2();` vc está gerando uma nova instância da `Form2`, e consequentemente o a variável `idselecionada` ainda não foi setada.

Uma alternativa é criar um construtor na `Form2` que receba um `Form` como parâmetro:

```c#
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form _formularioPai = null;

    public Form2(Form formulario)
    {
        _formularioPai = formulario;
    }
}
```

Então no evento `dataGridView1_CellClick` poderia atribuir diretamente o valor selecionado em uma variável da instância de `Form1`.